# How to read memory usage?

Tags: memory-usage

Well I'm pretty confused with the memory usage in ubuntu (probably linux in general)

TL;DR: Memory usage is 70%. When ich check `top`, `htop`, `ps aux` etc. I can see there should be a memory usage of ~10%.

Why is *anyone*  saying my usage is around 70%? What do I've to understand to get this?

---

## UPDATE:

```
free -h 

         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      7.8G       7.4G       419M       760K       851M       730M
-/+ buffers/cache:       5.8G       2.0G
Swap:           0B         0B         0B

###########################################################################

top -b n1 | head -n 5

top - 15:16:53 up 13:09,  2 users,  load average: 1.49, 1.43, 1.52
Tasks: 258 total,   1 running, 257 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  4.8 us,  1.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 92.2 id,  0.8 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   8169808 total,  7740972 used,   428836 free,   871604 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.   748248 cached Mem
```

An image of htop, ordered by `MEM%` - you can see there are 6 of8 gb memory reserved. But when you sum the values of the `MEM%` column you get a much lower percentage then 6gb. 
[image: ...]

Comment: Well, can you show us the output of `top -b -n1 | head -5` and `free -h`?

Comment: you can always install a software called system load indicator from software center

Comment: What is telling you that your memory usage is 70%?

Comment: @muru done. ;-)

Comment: @Brettetete you might have many small process together combining to 5GB of RAM used. Check the output of `echo $(ps -o rss= ax | tr '\n' +) 0 | bc` (should be around 5x10^6).

Comment: @muru it is around 5x10^5. I've checked htop.. It is hardly 1gb with alle the small processes.

Comment: @Brettetete you might need to use `sudo` with `ps` there. Even so, order-of-magnitude gap is very high. Possibly a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Type `free -h` in console. You will get something like this:

             `total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           15G       9,1G       6,1G       270M       524K       7,6G
-/+ buffers/cache:       1,5G        13G
Swap:           0B         0B         0B`

The first line says that out of 15G memory installed (marketologist's 16)  I have 9 used for apps and 7,6 for filesystem cache. The third line shows that I have swap disabled.

Comment: The `free` column shows how much memory system is ready to free up on demand *immediately*, witrhout much adverse effect on performance of other things. It is a part of `cache` and `shared` volumes.