# Lagging when running VS Code + GitKraken

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, performance, memory-usage

I do programming on my laptop.

When I open [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) without [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com) or vice versa, my laptop runs normally.

But always lagging when I open them both.

Here is my system specs:

- Acer Aspire E5-475G.
- Intel Core i3-6100U (2.3 GHz, 3MB L3 Cache).
- Nvidia GeForce 940MX with 2 GB Dedicated VRAM.
- 2 GB DDR4 Memory.
- **ChaletOS 16.04.2 LTS 64-bit (Xubuntu based).**

The CPU and memory usages are not reaching their peak.

Other processes:

- XAMPP.
- Opera web browser.

So how to find what's wrong?

Should I upgrade my laptop?

## Update

```
yahya@Yahya-Aspire-E5-475G:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1,8G        1,3G        118M        168M        408M        111M
Swap:           15G        798M         15G
yahya@Yahya-Aspire-E5-475G:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1,8G        1,2G        112M        149M        477M        191M
Swap:           15G        879M         15G
yahya@Yahya-Aspire-E5-475G:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1,8G        1,2G        125M        140M        447M        181M
Swap:           15G        943M         15G
yahya@Yahya-Aspire-E5-475G:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1,8G        1,2G         97M        141M        506M        211M
Swap:           15G        1,0G         15G
```

The task manager shows memory usage 75% in average, so I think there's still enough space.

But I don't understand with the output of `free -h` above. What is the true free space of my memory?

Comment: Guessing your RAM is exhausted when running big apps. Please post the output of the command `free -h` when running those two apps. Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/550604/how-to-read-memory-usage

Comment: You don't need a 15G swap, it's useless, once the system starts swapping performance goes down and you're doomed. And don't attempt to use 2 electron apps with only 2G of RAM, either upgrade to 4/8G or use lighter apps (regular git + geany).

Comment: @ManuelGutierrez I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `free -h` output shows that your swap usage rises significantly. It means the contents of RAM get moved to [swap space](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-swap-what-is.html). Swap is placed on the HDD and it’s much slower than RAM (unless you are using SSD).

You can read about [swappiness](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157793/why-is-swap-being-used-even-though-i-have-plenty-of-free-ram) to learn why swap is used before RAM is physically exhausted. But since your swap usage is higher than the RAM space available, the RAM size *does not suffice* to hold all the data – and this is needed for the smooth performance.

Comment: The swappiness in my OS has the initial value of `10`. Increasing its value really prevents lagging when I open those apps. But I cannot tell whether this change _degrades_ the overall performance, at least for now. I know that I'm running a (local) web server on my laptop, so it probably behaves like a server.